# replaceScene() messes up a public variable

Tags: c++, ios, mobile, cross-platform, cocos2d-x

I am porting a game from cocos2d-iphone 2.x to cocos2d-x 3.x.
Have to solve a few problems, including a major crash - the subject of this post.

It has been determined that the crash happens because SOMETIMES, my replaceScene call results in a messed-up important public variable.

My class:

```
class Player : public cocos2d::Sprite
{
public:
    ....
    cocos2d::Vec2 desiredPosition;
    ....
```

My Layer methods:

```
Scene* GameLevelLayer::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = GameLevelLayer::create();
    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);
    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

bool GameLevelLayer::init()
{
    // super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    ....
    player = (Player*) cocos2d::Sprite::create("sprite_idle_right@2x.png");
    player->setPosition(Vec2(100, 50));
    player->desiredPosition = player->getPosition();
    ....
    this->schedule(schedule_selector(GameLevelLayer::update), 1.0/60.0);
    ....
    return true;
}

void GameLevelLayer::endGame(bool won) {
    ....
    MenuItem* display;
    if (currentLevel < lastLevel && won) {
        ++currentLevel;
        display = MenuItemImage::create("next.png" ,"next.png" ,"next.png",
            CC_CALLBACK_1(GameLevelLayer::replaceSceneCallback, this));
    } else {
        // Lost the game
        currentLevel = 1;
        display = MenuItemImage::create("replay.png", "replay.png", "replay.png",
            CC_CALLBACK_1(GameLevelLayer::replaceSceneCallback, this));
    }
    ....
}

void GameLevelLayer::replaceSceneCallback(Ref* sender) {
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(this->createScene());
}
```

The member being messed is the desiredPosition. It is changed inside update() method. The problem is that update() gets an already messed-up desired position. It is only messed-up after a scene was being replaced. The problem happens once in 10 runs, or so. It even appears that when update() is called first time after the scene has been replaced, desiredPosition set to some garbage. is I was unable to learn more.

My Player class does not have a separate constructor.

Please advise.

Comment: `cocos2d::Sprite::create` creates a `Sprite`, not a `Player`, so you have undefined behaviour all over the place. It's just bad luck that your code works sometimes.

Comment: That's not a constructor, it's a factory function. It does not create a Player. You're writing outside the created object, which is undefined.

Comment: I meant that create() calls the constructor, as in: Sprite *sprite = new (std::nothrow) Sprite(); Perhaps, you are correct. Gotta think about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to initialize another instance variable. That instance variable is used to calculate the desiredPosition.